# how to plot a combined histogram with different datasets in r

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have 2 datasets and I am trying to find a better way of visualizing my results. Can you please help me to plot the 2 histograms on 1 histogram so it is easier to compare?

data1:

```
count <- c('10', '15', '16','16','29')
drug <- c('ibuprofen','aleve','tylenol','claritin', 'ozempic')
```

data2:

```
count <- c('150', '1000', '15','1','234','452','692')
drug <- c('ibuprofen','aleve','tylenol','xanax','gilenya','humira','tums')
```

This is what I have tried but it is not showing a histogram as I want.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = data1, aes(x=count, y=reorder(drug, count), color = "red")) + 
  geom_point(data = data2, aes(x=count, y=reorder(drug, count)))
```

Can you please help me produce a histogram that has both histograms so I can visualize the drugs side by side, add the count to the bars and also have the datasets color be black and gray. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

data1 <- data.frame(count = c(10, 15, 16, 16, 29), 
                    drug = c("ibuprofen", "aleve", "tylenol", "claritin", "ozempic"))
data2 <- data.frame(count = c(150, 1000, 15, 1, 234, 452, 692), 
                    drug = c("ibuprofen", "aleve", "tylenol", "xanax", "gilenya", "humira", "tums"))

combined_data <- data1 %>% 
  mutate(data = "data1") %>% 
  bind_rows(data2 %>% 
              mutate(data = "data2")) %>%
  complete(drug, data, fill = list(count = 0))  


ggplot(combined_data, aes(x = drug, y = count, fill = data)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = count), vjust = -0.5, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("steelblue3", "red3"))+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 12))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking to plot the counts, you could make both data sources into data frames, make a variable that identifies the source, and then use the `bar` geometry to make a side-by-side bar plot:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
df1 <- data.frame(
count  = c(10, 15, 16,16,29),
drug  = c('ibuprofen','aleve','tylenol','claritin', 'ozempic'))

df2 <- data.frame(
  count = c(150, 1000, 15,1,234,452,692), 
  drug = c('ibuprofen','aleve','tylenol','xanax','gilenya','humira','tums'))

df1$source <- "DF1"
df2$source <- "DF2"
df_both <- bind_rows(df1, df2)
df_both <- df_both %>% complete(drug, source, fill=list(count = 0))
ggplot(df_both, aes(x=count, y=drug, fill=source)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat = "identity") + 
  labs(x="Count", y="")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-01-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I really really appreciate your help. Can you help me add counts to each bar and also how can I change the colors of the source to black and gray? Thank you!